# Não consigo estender uma classe de JFrame no Eclipse

Tags: java

Estou tentando estender uma classe de JFrame para criar uma janela, porém no eclipse aparece o seguinte erro:

configure build path
-Open the Java build path property page of project "Chat"

O código seria esse:

```
import javax.swing.*;

      public class AppChat extends JFrame{

}
```

Comment: Recria o projeto. Parece ser problema de classpath mas não da pra saber sem mais detalhes.

Comment: Ou vai em `Project > Clean...` e clica em clean para limpar o projeto.